# My alt tab thumbnails are super large

Tags: resolution, icons, alt-tab

I was switching from a 4k display set at 1080p back to a display natively 1080p and the thumbnails in alt tab stayed massive [Image of icons in alt tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RhUg.png)

with more than 4 windows they just go off the screen. how can i revert it back to normal?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 11 after switching between a 4k display to a 1080p display.
What worked for me is going to Settings -> System -> Display, changing the Display resolution value to a different one, and then back to the desired one (or just selecting Revert on the prompt message)